# Express App runs on local but not remote server - 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

Tags: node.js, express, npm, ubuntu-16.04

I have a simple express app https://github.com/stuartabrown/express-google-assistant/tree/feature/new-simple-react.  It all runs fine locally.

However when I pull my code down to my remote server (Ubuntu 16.04, Node version v12.3.1, NPM v6.9.0) and run `npm install` and then `npm start` I get errors:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'npm audit'
Require stack:
- /home/stuart/express-google-assistant/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:527:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:681:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/stuart/express-google-assistant/index.js:5:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:641:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:837:10) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/home/stuart/express-google-assistant/index.js' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! express-starter-kit@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the express-starter-kit@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/stuart/.npm/_logs/2019-05-24T20_47_26_272Z-debug.log
```

Output of /home/stuart/.npm/_logs/2019-05-24T20_47_26_272Z-debug.log is

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.3.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle express-starter-kit@1.0.0~prestart: express-starter-kit@1.0.0
6 info lifecycle express-starter-kit@1.0.0~start: express-starter-kit@1.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle express-starter-kit@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle express-starter-kit@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/stuart/express-google-assistant/node_modules/.bin:/home/stuart/bin:/home/stuart/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
9 verbose lifecycle express-starter-kit@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/stuart/express-google-assistant
10 silly lifecycle express-starter-kit@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node index.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle express-starter-kit@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle express-starter-kit@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: express-starter-kit@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:200:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
14 verbose pkgid express-starter-kit@1.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/stuart/express-google-assistant
16 verbose Linux 4.4.0-148-generic
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
18 verbose node v12.3.1
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error express-starter-kit@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the express-starter-kit@1.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

***EDIT***

package.json details are:

```
{
    "name": "express-starter-kit",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node -r dotenv/config index.js"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "actions-on-google": "^2.0.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
        "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
        "ngrok": "^3.1.1"
    }
}
```

I'm a bit stumped as to how to resolve this, any help much appreciated.

Comment: `Error: Cannot find module 'npm audit'` can you post your package.json file?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio thanks. I have added this now

Comment: OMG, I just saw the reference in my index.js.  Thanks!